# MySQL transaction with thousands of Inserts - how many "round trips" does it take?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I've got C# code that accesses MySQL through ODBC.

It creates a transaction, does a few thousand insert commands, and then commits.
Now my question is how many "round trips", so to speak, happen against the DB server? I mean, does it simply transmit every insert command to the DB server, or does it cache/buffer them and send them in batches? And is this configurable in any way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

MySQL has an extended SQL style that can be used, where mass inserts are put in several at a time:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `event`)  VALUES (1, 94263), (2, 75015), (3, 75015);
```

I will usually collect a few hundred insert-parts into a string before running the SQL query itself.  This will reduce the overhead of parsing and communication by batching them yourself.

Comment: Any idea how many sets of parenthesis (),(),() are to be considered as 'large'? What I mean to ask is, after how many extended insert rows (= sets of parenthesis after VALUES ) in 1 query should we consider making a new query?

Comment: It depends as to the size of the data, but it's a toss-up between personal choice and database traffic limits (eg Mysql's 'max allowed packet' size). I generally do somewhere around 100.  It's just a little extra time if there's less per packet, and I don't want to risk any problems.

Comment: However, how to solve the problem of sql injection while concating sql string?

Answer (score 4):

There is no limit on the number of rows per se; The limit is on the number of bytes transferred to the server.

You could build the bulk insert up to the number of bytes specified in 'max allowed packet'. If I wanted to use the least amount of inserts I would try that.

Answer (score 2):

It does one round trip per query you submit (regardless of whether it's in a transaction or not).

It is possible, in MySQL, to use "extended insert" syntax which allows you to insert several (or indeed, many) rows in a single statement. This is generally considered a Good Thing.

Answer (score 2):

A round trip to the DB server is not the same as a round trip to  the database on disk.

Before you decide that the round trips are a bottleneck,  do some actual measurements.

There are ways to insert multiple rows with a single insert, depending on your DBMS.  Before you invest the coding effort, figure out whether it's likely to do you any good.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your code, but I'm assuming you are executing the statements one at a time. So, you will get one round trip per insert statement.

In MSSql you can execute multiple inserts in a single statement:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery "insert table values (1)  insert table values (2)"
```

So you can create a big string and execute it (I think it will have a limit), I assume this will work for MySQL.

Also in MSSQL you have a batch inserter (lookup "SqlBulkCopy"), in MySQL perhaps try [loading the data from a temp file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html).

Comment: I do not know about the ODBC connection of MySQL, but MySQL itself allows to concat several commands in a single execution. Also, you can do smth. like "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('hello', 'bye'), ('what', 'ever');" so answering nickf's question withe the given information is a bit hard. :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you invoke the SQL statement. I tried it once with MySQL JDBC driver and got an error saying the limit is 1MB but it is configurable.

I didn't bother to try to configure it and just split the SQL statements into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 0):

The limit of data that will be send depends on your server so the maximal length of multiple insert statements is automagically adjusted to fit. The bottleneck is a packet length and a buffer length.

See the `net_buffer_length` and `max_allowed_packet` variable descriptions for more info:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_buffer_length
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet

In some cases you can adjust these (e.g. when dumping data) to not generate inserts that are too long yet preserve multiple inserts. Be aware that if you have some blobs in your tables or any other long values that might exceede values of the mentioned variables you may get errors or incomplete data.

Answer (score -2):

When using MySQL 4.x a few years ago, we ran into a hard limit on query size that was not configurable.

This probably won't help you much as:

1. I don't remember what the hard limit was.
2. You're probably not using MySQL 4.x.
3. We weren't using transactions.

Good luck!